# How to run my GitHub Repository through terminal: creating the run file

Tags: java, bash

I created a repository on GitHub that has a few files of java I wrote. I am trying to run the repository through my terminal. I am wondering what commands I need to enter in the terminal as well as what I need to write in the run file within the repository. Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/mowteam/JAVA-THINGS but I will try to provide the necessary code in my question.

Currently, I have created a run file in the repository as well as terminal commands so that I can run my repository.

Terminal Commands:

```
    git clone https://github.com/mowteam/JAVA-THINGS
    cd JAVA-THINGS
    ./run
```

File Name: run

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    javac src/*.java
    java -cp src/ NewYearClock
    rm src/*.class
```

(note that I put the file I want to run in a folder named src and the file's name is NewYearClock as well as the class name in the file)

However, I keep receiving "Permission Denied" after I enter the ./run command. Therefore, I think the run file is the issue. I got the run file from another repository that I found and then changed the names so that is likely the cause of the issue. Does anyone know what is causing the 'permission denied' or how to fix the run file? Note: I don't know server-side coding. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you put in that file depends on what you want it to do.

I'm not a Java expert, but the current file looks at least semi-reasonable. You're compiling your code, running it, then removing the compiled version.

Your error isn't entirely clear (please include the entire, exact error message next time), but I suspect that it's just a permission error. On Unix-like systems, only files with the [execute bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)) set for the user running the code will be executed. Make your `run` file executable, e.g.

```
chmod +x run
```

then try again. As a side note, this is the only permission bit that Git cares about. You'll see that Git now views the file as modified, and you will probably want to commit that change.

Answer (score -1):

Before running from the terminal, SSH or HTTPS mapping is to be done. With this, connection between the local desktop/machine/server from where you are trying to access the Git repository and GIT will be established.

1. Generate the SSH key on local machine from where you are trying to access the repository
2. Under your git profile settings in GITlab/hub, add that key
3. Along with this, you need to configure username and  email in .gitconfig file

Comment: What do you put in the .gitconfig file? The other repository I am looking at has a file named '.gitignore' and it has the following code: .DS_Store
*.class

Comment: This is completely irrelevant. The question is poorly tagged, but OP is asking about how to run their Java code. Git and GitHub have nothing whasoever to do with it.